# yii2 frontend and backend not working on shared server

Tags: php, shared-hosting, yii2

We had build one project in yii2. It is working fine on local server. But it not working on shared server. I tried lot in htaccess but still not working for me.It gives me 500 internal server error

Frontend htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Backend htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: The first step would be to check logs to see why the 500 error is being returned. The 2nd step is to make sure the permissions you have are correct for owner and group. The last step would be to die(); out during your code until you find out what's causing the 500 ISE.

Comment: Even slightly different PHP versions can end up throwing 500 exceptions. The log is your friend.

Comment: I can't check log. Because i don't have credentials for that. This is shared server and i am working with FTP.

Comment: Usually they'll be somewhere where you have access to. Change your host if they won't you give you access to your apache logs, since they *can* be saved separately for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the server does not support 16-bit .php files.
Some editors (such as Notepad on Windows) will **always** add a byte-order mark (BOM) when you save a file as UTF-8, so make sure you use a text editor where you can save the file without the BOM.
I had exactly the same problem and it took me ages to debug the problem because the text in both formats looks identical when viewed.
The problem is quite a show-stopper when using session_start() because the file must begin with

Comment: Must begin with ...what?!

Comment: ... must begin with <php with **no** spaces before. (Sorry 'bout that, I ran out of space)